# densityplot() for Mice object

Tags: r, r-mice

I ran an imputation of 50 datasets:

```
imp3 <- mice(FOR, m=50, method=meth3, predictorMatrix=pred3, maxit=100, seed=123)


densityplot (imp3, ~ trs1sex)
```

The densityplot does not show 50 red (imputed) lines. Why is this the case and can I change this?

To geht an impression, these are 20 rows of my data:

```
structure(list( 
    Lerngr = c(1101, 1101, 1101, 1101, 1101, 1101, 1101, 1101, 
    1101, 1101, 1101, 1101, 1102, 1102, 1102, 1102, 1102, 1103, 
    1103, 1103), trs1jgs = structure(c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 
    trs1sex = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), trs.s1.mig = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L), s1alt = c(8.91666666666667, 8.33333333333333, 
    8.58333333333333, 9.66666666666667, 8.5, 8.16666666666667, 
    8.91666666666667, 8.75, 8.91666666666667, 8.75, 8.25, 8.41666666666667, 
    8.16666666666667, 9, 9, 8.41666666666667, 8.66666666666667, 
    9.66666666666667, 10.0833333333333, 10.6666666666667), hisei08 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1geh1 = c(4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA), s1geh2 = c(3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, NA), s1geh3 = c(4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, NA), s1geh4 = c(4, 
    4, 4, 3, NA, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, NA
    ), s1geh5 = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    3, 1, 4, 4, NA), s1ukaa1 = c(4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4), s1ukaa2 = c(4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 
    3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2), s1ukaa3 = c(3, 
    1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3), 
    s1ukaa4 = c(3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 2, 4, 2), s1ukaa5 = c(4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2), s1ukaa6 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3), s1uuka1 = c(4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2), 
    s1uuka2 = c(4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, NA), s1uuka3 = c(4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
    3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, NA), s1uuka4 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, NA), s1uuka5 = c(4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, NA), 
    s1uuka6 = c(4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 
    4, 3, 1, 4, NA), s1uuka7 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA), s1uuka8 = c(4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, NA), s1uuka9 = c(3, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA), 
    s1umoa1 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, NA), s1umoa2 = c(4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA), s1umoa3 = c(4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, NA), s1umoa4 = c(4, 
    2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA), 
    s1utpa1 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, NA), s1utpa2 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA), s1utpa3 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, NA), s1ukab1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1ukab2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1ukab3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1ukab4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1ukab5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1ukab6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1uukb1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1uukb2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1uukb3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1uukb4 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1uukb5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1uukb6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1uukb7 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1uukb8 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1uukb9 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1umob1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1umob2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1umob3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1umob4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1utpb1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1utpb2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), s1utpb3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), s1uts1_r = c(2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2), s1uts2_r = c(1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4), s1uts3_r = c(1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1), 
    s1uts4_r = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 
    3, 3, 1, 1, NA), s1uts5_r = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 
    1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, NA, NA), s1uac1 = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, NA), s1uac2 = c(4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 1, 2, NA
    ), s1uac3 = c(3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 3, 4, NA), s1uac4 = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, NA), s1uac5 = c(3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 
    2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, NA), s1uac6 = c(4, 
    4, 3, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, NA
    ), s1udi1_r = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), s1udi2_r = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1), s1udi3_r = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 
    3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1), s1udi4 = c(4, 
    3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
    s1udi5 = c(4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    2, NA, 4, 4), s1udi6_r = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
    3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), s1udi7_r = c(1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), s1udi8 = c(4, 
    2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
    s1udi9_r = c(1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 
    3, 1, 1, 1, 1), s1usl1 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 
    4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, NA, 4, 4), s1usl2 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4), s1usl3 = c(4, 
    3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4), 
    s1usl4 = c(1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 
    4, 1, 4, 4), s1usl5 = c(1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 
    2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), s1uad1 = c(NA, 0, 10, 50, 15, 
    NA, 30, 25, 40, 50, 50, 55, 65, 25, 70, 40, 60, NA, 35, 25
    ), s1uad2 = c(4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 5, 3, 3, 4), s1uad3 = c(4, 1, 5, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4), s1uad4 = c(4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 
    5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4), s1uad5 = c(4, 
    1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4), 
    s1uad6 = c(5, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, NA), s1uad7 = c(5, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, NA), s1uad8 = c(5, 1, 5, 4, 2, 5, 
    5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, NA), s1skm1 = c(3, 
    4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, NA, 4), 
    s1skm2 = c(3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
    4, 2, 3, 4), s1skm3 = c(4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 
    4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3), s1skd1 = c(4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, NA, 3), s1skd2 = c(4, 
    2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3), 
    s1skd3 = c(4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 3), s1skd4 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, NA, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3), s1intm1 = c(4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, NA, 4, 3, 4, 4), s1intm2 = c(4, 
    3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4), 
    s1intm3 = c(4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
    3, 1, 2, 3, 3), s1intd1 = c(4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3), s1intd2 = c(4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4), s1intd3 = c(4, 
    1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, NA, 4, 4, 4, 3), 
    s1zo1 = c(3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 
    3, NA, 3, 3), s1zo2 = c(3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 
    3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3), s1zo3 = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 
    4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3), s1zo4 = c(3, 3, 1, 
    4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3), s1zo5 = c(3, 
    3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3), 
    s1zo6 = c(4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 
    3, 3, 3, 3), s1zo7 = c(4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3), s1zo8 = c(4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3), s1zo9 = c(4, 3, 1, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), s1zo10 = c(3, 
    3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2), 
    s1zo11 = c(1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 
    4, 1, 3, 1), s1zo12 = c(3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2), s1zo13 = c(4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2), s1ab1 = c(4, 2, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4), s1ab2 = c(4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4), 
    s1ab3 = c(4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 3, 4), s1ab4 = c(3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 3), s1lf1 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3), s1lf2 = c(4, 1, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3), s1lf3 = c(4, 
    1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3), 
    s1sls_plus10 = c(39, 46, 33, 54, 44, 32, 50, 42, 42, 39, 
    38, 49, 55, 37, 34, 49, 43, 34, 46, 26), s1vsl = c(4, 13, 
    2, 9, 9, 1, 18, 0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 4, 3, 17, 8, 1, 3, 1), 
    s1lvdm = c(5, 14, 8, 8, 13, 7, 9, 17, 21, 8, 17, 12, 5, 19, 
    5, 7, 7, 2, 8, 15), s12cft = c(5, 11, 10, 8, 7, 6, 10, 10, 
    13, 6, 11, 7, 12, 8, 7, 11, 7, 5, 10, 2)), class = c("rowwise_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: When I run this with: `library(mice)
imp <- mice(boys, m=50, maxit=1, seed=123); 
densityplot(imp, ~hc)` It does show 50 red lines.

Comment: Hi Quinten, I added some data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the data was indeed imputed? To verify, check whether the `imp3$chainMeans` element in the `mids` object contains any values. If so, try using `ggmice` for visualization:

```
ggmice(imp, aes(x = trs1sex, group = .imp)) +
  geom_density()
```